# How to Scrape a search form in scrapy

Tags: search, scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy to scrape a website that has a search form but it's hard to do concurrent requests given how it works:
when you perform a search, it kind of creates a session around the search and you cannot have several searches at the same time, otherwise you cannot access the results of the previous searches anymore.

For example:

Starting a search with criteria A, it redirects to a page with an ID and the details of each result reuse this ID:

```
list.do?anchor=51edc79.0
details.do?anchor=51edc79.0.0
details.do?anchor=51edc79.0.1
```

If I start a new search with criteria B, it's a new ID:

```
list.do?anchor=5200109.0
details.do?anchor=5200109.0.0
details.do?anchor=5200109.0.1
```

But now the results of the 1st search are not accessible anymore:

```
details.do?anchor=51edc79.0.2 => cannot find
details.do?anchor=51edc79.0.3 => cannot find
```

I could do only one request at a time to make sure the 2nd search won't start until all the results of the 1st search are fetched but I'd still like to make concurrent requests to get the results of one search more quickly.
So the idea would be to not start the 2nd search until all the results of a search are fetched.

How would you do that in scrapy?

When I allowed multiple requests (**`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`**) and use priorities, the 2nd search started before all the pages from the first search were done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally sessions only depend on cookies, so you'll have to manage multiple cookies with the same spider, and [`cookiejars` are the solution here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider)

Only make every search request with a different cookiejar, remember to keep passing the cookiejar with all the related requests.

To control the cookies from the beginning of the spider try this:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    number_of_sessions = 5

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.number_of_sessions):
            yield Request(
                'homepage.com', 
                 meta={'cookiejar': i}, 
                 dont_filter=True, 
                 callback=self.parse,
            )
```

Use the `dont_filter` argument so scrapy won't filter those as duplicated requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it but the IDs I see in the search are not actually real sessions so when I start a new search using a new criteria in a cookiejar, it errors out (the server responds with a 500 because I think there is no session created on the server). It seems that the real session is created with the start url when accessing the home page.  So I have to use the cookiejar on the homepage (`Home -> Search -> Result`). That makes it complicated since I used the homepage as the starting point to get the criteria values before launching a search on each criteria. :-/

Comment: then you have to control the cookiejars since the beginning of the crawl, check my updated answer

Comment: Hum maybe I am missing something but from what I understand, in each session, I still have the original problem: within a session, I cannot move to the next search until all the results have been fetched. I'll see if I can use the cookiejar in a different way. Thanks anyway.